# How to show a block on the user profile page but not the user edit page?

Tags: 7, blocks, users

I have added a block to a region and set it so that it shows on user profile pages.

However, I want the block to be displayed only on the profile pages, not on the profile edit pages.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can use PHP in block visibility settings page

Comment: @NikhilMohan Is that enough for my need ? Can you show some example code ? please

Comment: What is that block? your written module or an exists block?

Comment: @MohammadAliAkbari i have written module.

Comment: so you can return empty $block array in /user/%uid/edit, something like `if(arg(0) == 'user' && is_number(arg(1)) && empty(arg(2))) ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, enable the PHP filter module and give yourself permissions to use PHP in order to input PHP on the Block visibility settings page.

On the Block visibility settings page, you can check for an argument like this:

```
<?php 
if(arg(0) == 'user' && arg(2) != 'edit' )
return true;
else 
return false 
?>
```

Also, see my answer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155305/in-drupal-7-how-do-i-make-a-block-visible-on-the-user-view-page-but-invisible).

Answer (score 0):

These days there is another alternative available ... ***which doesn't require the PHP filter to be enabled*** (which you should try to avoid whenever possible) ... Just use the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless.
>
> Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
>
> Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
>
> What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) "***check the path of the current page***" (so that the block is only shown on your pages with a path that **starts with** "`user/`", but not on those pages that have a path **ending with** "`/edit`").

For an illustration of how to use this module, refer to my answer to "[How to stop a Views block from displaying to admins, such as user/1?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109984/how-to-stop-a-views-block-from-displaying-to-admins-such-as-user-1/193173#193173)". It includes a Rules Component (in Rules export format), which you should replace by this variation of it to make it match your specific question):

```
{ "rules_block_visibility_show_on_selected_profile_pages" : {
    "LABEL" : "Show block on selected profile pages",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "module" : { "label" : "Module", "type" : "text" },
      "delta" : { "label" : "Delta", "type" : "text" },
      "result" : { "label" : "Result", "type" : "boolean", "parameter" : false }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "AND" : [
          { "text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
              "match" : "user\/",
              "operation" : "starts"
            }
          },
          { "NOT text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
              "match" : "\/edit",
              "operation" : "ends"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "result" ], "value" : "1" } } ],
    "PROVIDES VARIABLES" : [ "result" ]
  }
}
```

Also, if you'd replace the 2nd Rules Condition in the above Rules Component with something using an appropriate regular expression, you could even further refine it, to check for something like "`user/uid/edit`", whereas `uid` corresponds with some user's uid, and so that the block would be shown anyway on pages with a path like "`user/with/some/other/path/edit`".

Answer (score 0):

On Drupal 8, this is possible to be done with the [Block Exclude Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_exclude_pages) module. You would set it like this:

```
/user
/user/*
!/user/*/*
```

This would cause the block to be displayed on the regular user profile page (www.example.com/user, or www.example.com/user/5), but not on www.example.com/user/5/edit.

This module establishes the (!) sign as a mark for denying access on a given rule.